# Different values for same integral calculated via contour integration

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, calculus

Perhaps this question should be asked on the Math community, but I think that, because of the specific example that I will cite, I might get a better insight on my doubt here.

So, why can we get two different results (mathematically) according to whether we choose to circumvent or to contour a pole when calculating an integral? The most obvious example being the Feynman prescription on QFT and related calculations.

I know that most integrals to which contour integration techniques are useful doesn't exist and, in these cases, what we do is 'just' a way of giving them a quantitative meaning (call it the Cauchy's Principal Value, if you want), however still can't understand intuitively or formally what causes the difference on the values calculated from different choices of contour.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic It can be migrated there, by me (don't know if I have to do something for it to be done).

Comment: If you flag for migration, the post will enter the review list.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I am studying the Klein-Gordon propagators and am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a consequence of the [Cauchy Goursat Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) and [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem): the first tells you that an integral is invariant under an homotopy of a contour *unless* the the region between a contour and its homotopic image includes a new singularity; the second tells you that the integral changes by  $2\,\pi\,i$ times the residue of any new pole that becomes included under an homotopy as long as the contour does not contain branch points or cross brach cuts.

The intermediate case, that leads to the Cauchy principal value, is where the contour goes exactly through the pole; this behavior can be understood by "dinting" the contour inwards by a semicircular dint of radius $\epsilon$ to avoid the pole and then evaluating the limit of the explicit calculation of the contour on this semicircle as $\epsilon\to0$.

As to the physical meaning of all these variations, one has to look in detail at the physical assumptions underlying the operations on a case-by-case basis to determine this meaning.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the method itself  (that is, to find some suitable contour to, after using the residue theorem, compare the integral over the interesting interval with the resting ones) but yet can't figure out why the result considering a contour which include (inside the region) is different from the one that avoid the sigularity through which the contour would pass since the mathematical meaning of the principal value is just the integral evaluated on a symetric limiting interval (which should be independent of the operational procedure - as I can see). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry to comment on an older post, but I am studying the Klein-Gordon propagator and am running into the same issue of an integral giving different answers depending on the choice of contour. Based on your answer is it correct to say that we get different answers going from the Feynman propagator to the advanced propagator because the homotopy for the two contours introduces a new singularity?